# Testing a class: fixture not founded

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I'm learning Python from a book 'Python Crashed Course, 3rd Edition'.
For the final exercise 11-3 Employee in chapter 11:

I build my Employee class like this:

```
# 11-3 Employee
class Employee:
    """A class contains: a first name, a last name and an annual salary"""

    def __init__(self, first, last, salary):
        self.name = first + ' ' + last
        self.annual_salary = int(salary)

    def give_raise(self, raise_amount=''):
        if raise_amount:
            self.annual_salary += int(raise_amount)
        else:
            self.annual_salary += 5000

    def show_salary(self):
        print(f"${self.annual_salary}")
```

There is my test file:

```
import pytest
from employee import Employee


@pytest.fixture
def initial_info():
    """Create an instance of Employee"""
    bruce = Employee('Hongbo', 'Wei', 40000)
    return bruce


def test_give_default_raise(bruce):
    """Test if raising correctly salary by default"""
    bruce.give_raise()
    assert bruce.annual_salary == 45000


def test_give_custom_raise(bruce):
    """Test if raising salary correctly by providing parameter"""
    raise_amount = 6666
    bruce.give_raise(raise_amount)
    assert bruce.annual_salary == 46666
```

But when I run pytest, it says "fixture 'bruce' not found".
I have no idea why this happens.

The example on the book to test aonther program works fine and is relatively simple:

```
@pytest.fixture
def language_survey():
    question = "what language did you first learn to speak?"
    language_survey = AnonymouseSurvey(question)
    return language_survey
```

Doesn't the return statements can work with the whole objects of a class?

For my test file, it works fine if I don't use the fixture method.

```
import pytest
from employee import Employee


def test_give_default_raise(bruce):
    """Test if raising correctly salary by default"""
    bruce = Employee('Hongbo', 'Wei', 40000)
    bruce.give_raise()
    assert bruce.annual_salary == 45000


def test_give_custom_raise(bruce):
    """Test if raising salary correctly by providing parameter"""
    bruce = Employee('Hongbo', 'Wei', 40000)
    raise_amount = 6666
    bruce.give_raise(raise_amount)
    assert bruce.annual_salary == 46666
```

Comment: so where did you implement the fixture ?

Comment: in Pycharm Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How funny it is!

I just solved my problem by simply changing the function name under @pytest.fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def bruce():
```

So the name of the parameter passed in other functions has to be the same as the function just under @pytest.fixture